# Info regarding Disk/Drive partition in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, users, disk, administration

I am just starting to use Ubuntu. I have already installed it in VM.I am general user and not tech expert. So my question is

1. In windows generally there is one disk and then we partition them into different partitions which are label as C,D,E,F etc.What is equivalent of that in Ubuntu. As in windows OS we can see different drives graphically .IS it same possible in Ubuntu
2. During its installation its ask to create one account. Does that account have admin rights ??Are there any other account which is created automatically having admin rights

Comment: You use sudo for temporary admin rights. https://xkcd.com/149/ With Linux you can give more usable names to partiitons like Data, Games etc. If regularly using partition, better to permanently mount using fstab. You create mount point, add entry to fstab and give yourself ownership & permissions. If only used occasionally I like to label partition and then it automounts under the label, not an UUID which I do not know.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting Data partition can be on same HDD or SSD as system.

Answer (score 1):

1. In other operating systems than Windows we create mountpoints. A mountpoint can be a directory, but also a partition. The root filesystem has `/` as its mountpoint. You can have `/home/` as a mountpoint on the same disk and you can have a `/discworld/` as a mountpoint for a complete 2nd hard disk (a hdd for instance where `/` is on an sdd).

   Mountpoints are shown in lots of ways. From command line you could have this:

   ```
   $  df -H
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Mounted on
   /dev/sda1        25G    8G   17G /
   /dev/sdb        900G  300G  600G /u
   ```

   It will also be possible to see this from the desktop. Disk Usage Analyzer for instance ([google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=Disk%20Usage%20Analyzer%20linux&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0-7yIq-zyAhXOyaQKHYm3AGUQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=927)).
2. Yes, that is the admin account. And no; All other users (and that can be a 2nd, or 3rd admin) need to be created after installation.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply but by graphically i mean like when we open "this PC" or "file explorer" in  windows we can see drives .Is same/equivalent possible in ubuntu/linux?